# Assigning repeated loop output to one data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, mean, resampling

I have a data frame **train**. It looks like this:

```
> str(train)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4096 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ XY   : chr  "-0.253056407416539,0.0284760501437887" "-0.248966337417195,0.0327728517259305" "-0.244876267417851,0.0376197657997918" "-0.240786197418507,0.0430736699343487" ...
 $ Group: chr  "fa05,1" "fa05,1" "fa05,1" "fa05,1" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

> head(train)
                                      XY  Group
1: -0.253056407416539,0.0284760501437887 fa05,1
2: -0.248966337417195,0.0327728517259305 fa05,1
3: -0.244876267417851,0.0376197657997918 fa05,1
4: -0.240786197418507,0.0430736699343487 fa05,1
5: -0.236696127419163,0.0492435986076443 fa05,1
6: -0.232606057419819,0.0562149950068869 fa05,1
```

I have written code that resamples the column XY by group, separates the values in the column by "," into two separate columns, convert them to numerics and then take the mean of the X and Y columns separately for each Group. It works perfect and the output looks like this:

```
    Group.1         X         Y
1    fa05,0 0.3174567 1.1083954
2    fa05,1 0.2857464 1.0411072
3    fa10,0 0.2987560 1.1765904
4    fa10,1 0.2563579 1.1286934
5    fa20,0 0.3204026 1.0703147
6    fa20,1 0.2597907 1.1629019
7  flatfa,0 0.3191444 1.0399517
8  flatfa,1 0.2532680 1.1957248
9  flatsa,0 0.3252190 1.0506540
10 flatsa,1 0.3124151 0.8458343
11   sa05,0 0.2792419 1.1065144
12   sa05,1 0.2186174 1.2720533
13   sa10,0 0.3071584 1.3031327
14   sa10,1 0.3134321 1.0493272
15   sa20,0 0.3134320 1.1239246
16   sa20,1 0.2919554 1.2797494
```

Now I have tried to implement this in a loop, so that it is repeated 10 times and assigned to the same data frame. I have come up with this:

```
boot_means <- data.frame(Group.1 = rep(c(""), each=16*10),
                         X = rep(c(as.numeric("")), each=16*10),
                         Y = rep(c(as.numeric("")), each=16*10))

for (i in 1:10){
  train_resample <- setDT(train)[, .(XY=sample(XY, replace=T)), by = Group]
  train_sep <- train_resample %>% separate(XY, c("X", "Y"), ",") 
  train_sep$X <- as.numeric(train_sep$X)
  train_sep$Y <- as.numeric(train_sep$Y)
  resample_means <- aggregate(train_sep[, 2:3], list(train_sep$Group), mean)
  print(resample_means)
  boot_means[i] <- resample_means
}
```

It works as far as to "print(resample_means)" - here I get the expected output. But when I take a look at boot_means, the loop has assigned the Group-variable to all columns.

```
> head(boot_means)
  Group.1      X      Y
1  fa05,0 fa05,0 fa05,0
2  fa05,1 fa05,1 fa05,1
3  fa10,0 fa10,0 fa10,0
4  fa10,1 fa10,1 fa10,1
5  fa20,0 fa20,0 fa20,0
6  fa20,1 fa20,1 fa20,1
```

This is not what I want! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make `boot_means` a list and store the dataframe in it.

```
library(data.table)

boot_means <- vector('list', 10)

for (i in 1:10){
  train_resample <- setDT(train)[, .(XY=sample(XY, replace=T)), by = Group]
  train_sep <- train_resample %>% tidyr::separate(XY, c("X", "Y"), ",") 
  train_sep$X <- as.numeric(train_sep$X)
  train_sep$Y <- as.numeric(train_sep$Y)
  resample_means <- aggregate(train_sep[, 2:3], list(train_sep$Group), mean)
  boot_means[[i]] <- resample_means
}
#If you want everything in one dataframe.
combined_data <- rbindlist(boot_means)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much!